# Find Missing GraphQL Resolvers in Apollo

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

Using [apollo-server](https://www.apollographql.com/), if I attempt to define a graphql resolver that does not exist in my schema, the computer yells at me.

> [Error: Query.foo defined in resolvers, but not in schema]

This is good!

Is it possible, using the apollo (or other?) tools, to do the opposite?  That is, is there a way to have apollo tell me if there's a query, mutation, or subscription operation that's defined in my schema but *not* defined in my resolvers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an optional `resolverValidationOptions` object that can be passed to `makeExecutableSchema` to enforce some additional resolver validations as shown [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/graphql-tools/#makeexecutableschemaoptions):

> - `requireResolversForArgs` will cause `makeExecutableSchema` to throw an error if no resolve function is defined for a field that has arguments.
> - `requireResolversForNonScalar` will cause `makeExecutableSchema` to throw an error if a non-scalar field has no resolver defined. Setting this to `true` can be helpful in catching errors, but defaults to false to avoid confusing behavior for those coming from other GraphQL libraries.
> - `requireResolversForAllFields` asserts that all fields have a valid resolve function.
> - `requireResolversForResolveType` will require a `resolveType()` method for Interface and Union types. This can be passed in with the field resolvers as __resolveType(). False to disable the warning.
> - `allowResolversNotInSchema` turns off the functionality which throws errors when resolvers are found which are not present in the schema. Defaults to `false`, to help catch common errors.

None of them specifically targets *only* fields on the root types, but you may be able to make use of one or more.

These options are not exposed directly through ApolloServer, but you can always do:

```
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers, resolverValidationOptions })
const apollo = new ApolloServer({ schema })
```